# Left Join, But Exclude If Joined Table Contains Entry

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, inner-join

I know the title seems trivial, but the problem is a bit deeper than it seems at first sight.

I have the following 3 table structures:

```
user:  id, name
group: id, name
group_members: id, idUser, idGroup
```

There is a `group` for super admins that has an id=1.

I need to select all users that are **NOT** part of this group. However, the tricky part is when they are subscribed to the super admins group and other groups. I tried a LEFT JOIN and JOIN, but they get included in this case. I want to EXCLUDE them from the result if they are subscribed to the super admin group, regardless of the fact if they are subscribed to other groups or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT idUser FROM group_members WHERE idGroup = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

without a subquery

```
select idUSER from group_members
group by iduser
having sum(if(idgroup=1,1,0))=0
```